# ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server autoinstall

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

how to auto install ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server

Why does the following configuration not take effect?

**# cat iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg**

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then

```
set gfxmode=auto

insmod efi_gop

insmod efi_uga

insmod gfxterm

terminal_output gfxterm
```

fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black

set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5

menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server 1812" {

```
set gfxpayload=keep

linux   /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper **autoinstall ds='nocloud;s=/cdrom/'** ---

initrd  /casper/initrd
```

}

menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {

```
set gfxpayload=keep

linux   /casper/vmlinuz   boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---

initrd  /casper/initrd
```

}

menuentry "Check disc for defects" {

```
set gfxpayload=keep

linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---

initrd  /casper/initrd
```

}

submenu 'Boot and Install with the HWE kernel' {

menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server" {

```
set gfxpayload=keep

linux   /casper/hwe-vmlinuz   boot=casper quiet  ---

initrd  /casper/hwe-initrd
```

}

menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {

```
set gfxpayload=keep

linux   /casper/vmlinuz   boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---

initrd  /casper/initrd
```

}

}

**# cat iso/meta-data**

instance-id: focal-autoinstall

**# cat iso/user-data**

#cloud-config

autoinstall:

version: 1

locale: en_US.UTF-8

keyboard:

```
layout: us
```

identity:

```
hostname: ubuntu-server

username: ubuntu

password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
```

ssh:

```
allow-pw: true

install-server: true
```

...

Comment: Details are difficult to understand due to formatting problems. We can usually help with formatting but in this case there is a lot of ambiguity due to heavy manipulation of the pasted information. Remember that one character out of place can cause a config to not work.   Here's the formatting guide for reference: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code It's best if you don't manipulate what you are copy/pasting. Don't add/remove characters, line breaks, or spaces anywhere inside of your paste  -- instead, use code fences (three backticks on a line before and again on a line after the paste)

Answer (score 0):

[autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) for the live-server image was added in 20.04.  If you want to automate an 18.04 server install then you need to use [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html).

- `autoinstall` works with the *subiquity* "live-server" image starting with 20.04.
- `preseeding` works with the *debian-installer* "server" image.  This image was renamed "legacy-server" in 20.04 and is not available for newer releases.